# Can't get Toggle Switches to work in Asp.Net Webforms

Tags: html, css, asp.net, checkbox, toggle

I need to add a toggle switch that I can read from and set to tell me whether the user wants this activated or disabled.

I have this CSS which I have found in multiple different examples

```
    .switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

and using this HTML

```
    <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
     <span class="slider round"></span>
     </label>
```

But when I actually test it, it renders the HTML like this, which causes the toggle switches not to work
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFj0r.png)

The line marked in red is being added from somewhere and I can only see it if I go to inspect the element in chrome. I have no clue why this is happening, if I remove the line in question then the toggle switch will work as expected

I hope someone has a solution to this problem that has been bothering me for so long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CSS the [next-sibling combinator (+)](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) is used to set the checked styles on the `.slider` span. It will not match if HTML is generated by [ASP controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control?view=netframework-4.8) as in your example when using `<asp:CheckBox ... />` instead `<input type="checkbox">`, as there is a HTML element between the `input` and the `.slider` (so there is no next-sibling relation), which you also pointed out. To still get a match in that case, the [subsequent-sibling combinator (~)](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators) can be used instead the `next-sibling combinator` in the selectors of the checked styles.